# useEffect is not working for Autoselect Dropdown

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, dropdown

The scenario is when user save the new category, the Category dropdown should be re-rendered with new value. Unfortunately this is not happening.

[image]

I tried two approaches:

1. When the dependency array is set to ***category*** variable. In this case, the call to fetch categories is infinite as shown in below image.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCategoryList = async () => {
      const data = await categoryApi.getAllDD();
      setCategory(data);
    };
    fetchCategoryList();
  }, [category]);
```

[image]

2. When the dependency array is set to ***category.length*** variable. In this case, the useEffect does not get call at all.

```
  const [category, setCategory] = useState([]);
..
..
..
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCategoryList = async () => {
      const data = await categoryApi.getAllDD();
      setCategory(data);
    };
    fetchCategoryList();
  }, [category.length]);
```

```
            <Autocomplete
              disablePortal
              id="ddCategory"
              getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
              getOptionKey={(option) => option.id}
              options={category}
              sx={{ width: 300 }}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField {...params} label="Parent Category" />
              )}
              size="small"
              onChange={handleOnAutoCompleteInputChange}
            />

.
.
.

          const handleOnAutoCompleteInputChange = (
            e: React.SyntheticEvent,
            value: any,
            reason: string
          ) => {
            setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
              ...prevFormData,
              parentId: value?.id,
            }));
          };
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: can you please add codes of Category dropdown component?

Comment: Added autocomplete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of run fetchCategoryList on useEffect hook, you should run this function after click save button, for example:

```
 const handleClick = async()=>{
    // make request for save category or whatever you need to do
    const response = await request()
     // when we have response,then we ask for new category list
    if( res){
    const data = await fetchCategoryList();
    data && setCategoryList(data);
    }
  }
```

Comment: certainly I will but any idea why useEffect is not working?

Comment: useEffect keep track of dependencies changes, when you click on button to save something, it has no clue what happened. because categoryList is not changing when you click on the button. and in the first approach, you change list inside of useEffect, that changes dependency so it makes infinite request

Comment: it happens :) . best approach is to get initial category list in useEffect with no dependencies and for updating the list, use approach in the answer.